# Identifying treatments with non-zero effects

Tags: causality, treatment-effect, blocking

I have a complete block design experiment with a large number of treatments were I am trying to identify treatments with significant effects (positive or negative).  I know the [Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test)/[Durbin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin_test) tests can be used to test if all treatments have an equal effect, and post-hoc analysis can be done to identify *pairs* of treatments that differ.  However, what I am looking for is treatments whose effects are higher or lower than the over all *population*.

I found [a reference which provides a mechanism for estimating treatment effect](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/anova/chapter6-anova-bibd.pdf) in BIBD that seems like it can be applied to complete block designs.  However I am unclear on how to determine if any particular treatment effect is non-zero.

In other words, I want to know how to test $H_0: \tau_i = 0$ for the treatment effect, $\tau_i$, for any given treatment $i$.